# URL masking with .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, masking

I need a hardcore programmer to help me with URL masking.

So this is my situation.

1. My website www.michaelfotograf.dk/blog/ is the main site that needs to be configured.
2. I have another website/webhotel called www.umagepar.dk
3. www.umagepar.dk is redirected to www.michaelfotograf.dk/blog/
4. The blog is an ongoing project where i post a lot of stuff to get my ranking higher on google.
5. www.umagepar.dk which redirect to www.michaelfotograf.dk/blog/ is also a project on is own, so I do not want people to know, that it is a blog connected with www.michaelfotograf.dk/blog/
6. I therefore need to mask www.michaelfotograf.dk/blog/ so it will be called www.umagepar.dk in the URL in the searchbar at all times!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your host at `michaelfotograf.dk` will need to support *Addon* (multiple) domains (as it is called in cPanel).

1. In cPanel (for `michaelfotograf.dk`), setup `umagepar.dk` as an Addon domain, pointing to `michaelfotograf.dk/blog/`
2. Change the nameservers for `umagepar.dk` to point to the DNS at `michaelfotograf.dk`
3. Remove the redirection from `umagepar.dk` to `michaelfotograf.dk/blog/`
4. Redirect `michaelfotograf.dk/blog/` to `umagepar.dk` in order to prevent the user accessing the same content from different URLs (duplicate content).

.htaccess is only required to perform the final redirect, in order to prevent duplicate content - it is not necessary to perform the URL "masking".